# Lambda comparison with two numbers

Tags: java, lambda

I've been trying to do  the Java_Functional_programming course of stepik inside Intellij and have with this task 2.3.

> Write a lambda expression that accepts two integers arguments and returns max of them.
>
> Try not to use the `Math` library.
>
> Solution format. Submit your lambda expression in any valid format with `;` on the end.
>
> Examples: `(x, y) -> x + y; (x) -> { return x; };`

How I understand it, it's just an if/else with lambdas, so I tried

```
x = 10;y = 5; int nr  = (x,y) -> x > y ? x : y ;
```

But every time I check it's incorrect and I really don't get it. Maybe someone can help me?

Answer (score 2):

Your code

```
int nr  = (x, y) -> x > y ? x : y;
```

is trying to store a lambda expression in a variable declared as having type `int`. Your expression *returns* an `int` when it's applied but it isn't itself an `int`. I expect you want something like:

```
IntBinaryOperator max = (x, y) -> x > y ? x : y;
```

Then you can apply that expression with `max.applyAsInt(x, y)`

But given the instruction about solution format I expect you should just submit `(x,y) -> x > y ? x : y;`

Comment: Thank you very much.